# scrapy downloadmiddleware failed to schedule request from process_response

Tags: scrapy

I want to push the request which response code is 423 back to scheduler, so I create a downloadmiddleware:

```
class MyMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        if response.status == 423:
            return request
        else:
            return response
```

but it does not work, even the request is not in scheduler again.

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new request is probably getting filtered out by scrapy's dupefilter.

You can try addding `dont_filter=True` parameter:

```
def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
    if response.status == 423:
        request = request.replace(dont_filter=True)
        return request
    else:
        return response
```

Comment: @freyr no problem, though be careful, this middleware of yours can end up just retrying request endlessly.

Comment: @freyr if you feel that this answered your question please click the "accept answer" button to the left of the question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set these two settings to your `scrapy_settings`:

```
RETRY_HTTP_CODES=[423]
RETRY_TIMES=10
```

and scrapy will manage it for you.